Using ImageRenderer to plot Chart gives square, blurry image
I'm using SwiftUI Chart on MacOS to plot multiple waveforms for comparison.  I'd like to save any particular waveform as PNG via right click using ImageRenderer.
I've got it to save an image but the aspect ratio of the resulting PNG file does not match the Chart from the view.
Here's the full view:

And the saved file:

I've played around with the .scale property, but it scales in all directions.
Any suggestions?  Here is the relevant code:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

let colorList =
[
    NSColor.blue,
    NSColor.red,
    NSColor.purple,
    NSColor.green
]

struct ButtonPlot : View
{
    private var mOneBtn : TOneBtn
    private var mXStart : Float = 0
    private var mXEnd   : Float = 0
    private var mTrain  : Int
    
    init(train: Int, btn: TOneBtn)
    {
        mTrain  = train
        mOneBtn = btn
        
        if let xs = mOneBtn.dataPointList.first?.x
        {
            mXStart = xs - 0.001
        }
        
        if let xe = mOneBtn.dataPointList.last?.x
        {
            mXEnd = xe + 0.001
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("Button \(mTrain):\(mOneBtn.idx). \(mOneBtn.dataPointList.count) data points")
        
        chartBlock
        .contextMenu
        {
            Button("Save")
            {
                let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: chartBlock)
                renderer.scale = 3.0
                
                print("proposed: \(renderer.proposedSize)")
                print("scale: \(renderer.scale)")
                
                if let nsImage = renderer.nsImage
                {
                    let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: nsImage.tiffRepresentation!)
                    if let pngData = imageRep?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
                    {
                        let url = URL(filePath: "/Users/danny/Desktop/snapshot.png")
                        
                        do
                        {
                            try pngData.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
                            print("WROTE FILE")
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            print("Error saving \(url.path()) - \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var chartBlock : some View
    {
        Chart(mOneBtn.dataPointList)
        {
            LineMark(x: .value("x", $0.x), y: .value("y", $0.y))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
        .chartXScale(domain: mXStart ... mXEnd)
    }
    
}

struct BtnTrainView : View
{
    private let mTrain : TBtnTrain
    
    init(_ t: TBtnTrain)
    {
        mTrain = t
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("BtnTrainView")
        VStack()
        {
            Text("Button Train \(mTrain.idx)")
            ForEach(mTrain.btnList, id: \.self)
            {
                btn in
                ButtonPlot(train: mTrain.idx, btn: btn)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct MultiTrainView : View
{
    @EnvironmentObject private var mPlotter : DataPlotter
    
    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true)
        {
            HStack()
            {
                ForEach(mPlotter.buttonTrainList)
                {
                    train in
                    BtnTrainView(train)
                }
            }
            .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
        }
        .frame(height: 500)
    }
}


struct GraphView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var   mPlotter : DataPlotter
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text("\(mPlotter.buttonTrainList.count) Trains")
            
            MultiTrainView()
                .environmentObject(mPlotter)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
}

EDIT I
Good suggestion from Sweeper - I didn't realize you can append modifiers within the function call's parameter list.
Adding .aspectRatio fixes the aspect ratio but the resolution was still poor.  I played around with adding .frame, .scaleToFit() .scaleEffect and a few others.  The resolution was much better but the output image has the graph in the center surrounded by a large white space.  ie, the image size matches the .frame size but the Chart within doesn't scale.
For example, this:
let cb = chartBlock.frame(width: 1000, height: 500).aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit)
let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: cb)

Produces this output image. (I added the red border manually in an image editor to show the boundary)

How can I make the Chart larger within the image?

It'd be hard to get the aspect ratios to exactly match with what's on the screen, but if you have an aspect ratio you like, you can hardcode it in. e.g. ImageRenderer(content: chartBlock.aspectRatio(3, contentMode: .fit)).

Sweeper, that's a very good hint. Thanks!  Some success but some problems.  Please see "Edit I" above.

Your graph also has maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 100. Perhaps remove that if you want a bigger image? Only add it when showing it on the screen.

Based on Sweeper's comments, I played around with the .frame parameter at various locations in the code. After a lot of trial and error, this code produces the correct output:
struct ButtonPlot : View
{
    @EnvironmentObject private var mPlotter : DataPlotter
    
    private var mOneBtn : TOneBtn
    private var mXStart : Float = 0
    private var mXEnd   : Float = 0
    private var mTrain  : Int
    
    init(train: Int, btn: TOneBtn)
    {
        mTrain  = train
        mOneBtn = btn
        
        if let xs = mOneBtn.dataPointList.first?.x
        {
            mXStart = xs - 0.001
        }
        
        if let xe = mOneBtn.dataPointList.last?.x
        {
            mXEnd = xe + 0.001
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("Button \(mTrain):\(mOneBtn.idx). \(mOneBtn.dataPointList.count) data points")
        
        chartBlock
        .contextMenu
        {
            Button("Save")
            {
                let cb = chartBlock.aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit)
                let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: cb)
                
                if let nsImage = renderer.nsImage
                {
                    let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: nsImage.tiffRepresentation!)
                    if let pngData = imageRep?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
                    {
                        let url = URL(filePath: "/Users/danny/Desktop/snapshot.png")
                        
                        do
                        {
                            try pngData.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
                            print("WROTE FILE")
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            print("Error saving \(url.path()) - \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var chartBlock : some View
    {
        Chart(mOneBtn.dataPointList)
        {
            LineMark(x: .value("x", $0.x), y: .value("y", $0.y))
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
        .chartXScale(domain: mXStart ... mXEnd)
    }
}

